# Set Vector of Eigen Matrices to 0

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm adapting the Hough Transform for a special application, and for this I need to store a lot of Eigen Matrixes in a vector and I need them all to be 0 at the beginning.
This is how I have initialized this:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<int,30,150> HoughMatrix
std::vector<HoughMatrix> hough_spaces(num_spaces)
```

My question now is, what is the fastest way to make all elements of all those Matrixes equal to 0? 
I tried looping over each Vector element and do:

```
hough_spaces[i].setZero()
```

But that was rather slow. Is there a faster way? Or a way to directly initialize them as 0? 
Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the type of `Eigen::Matrix`?

Comment: How do you know, it's rather slow? Remember not to optimise prematurely

Comment: What constructors are available for the `Eigen::Matrix` class?

Comment: @Rietty it's an Eigen::Matrix<int,30,150> so 30x150 size and all Integer values

Comment: @cplusogl my whole code is done and I'm just trying to optimize it to get it to run in real time, and this step, setting to 0, is by far the slowest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `Eigen::Matrix<int,30,150>` will by default be aligned to 16 bytes, which on 64bit systems or with C++17 will most likely work properly, but you may otherwise face [some caveats](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html).
An easy way to workaround any issues regarding alignment is to write

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<int,30,150, Eigen::DontAlign> HoughMatrix;
```

Now the idiomatic way to write what you want would be to write

```
std::vector<HoughMatrix> hough_spaces(num_spaces, HoughMatrix::Zero());
```

However, this will result in a loop of `memcpy` calls (at least for gcc and clang: https://godbolt.org/z/ULixBm).

Alternatively, you could create a vector of uninitialized `HoughMatrix`es and apply `std::memset` on them:

```
std::vector<HoughMatrix> hough_spaces(num_spaces);
std::memset(hough_spaces.data(), 0, num_spaces*sizeof(HoughMatrix));
```

Note that for that to run without Eigen having to loop through all elements requires to have `HoughMatrix` not aligned (as shown at the beginning) or to disable alignment-assertions: https://godbolt.org/z/nDJqV5

If you don't actually need the `std::vector` functionality (mostly the ability to copy and resize), you could just allocate some memory using `calloc` and `free` it after usage. To be leak-safe, this can be encapsulated into a `std::unique_ptr`:

```
// unique_ptr with custom deallocator (use a typedef, if you need this more often):
std::unique_ptr<HoughMatrix[], void(&)(void*)> hough_spaces(static_cast<HoughMatrix*>(std::calloc(num_spaces, sizeof(HoughMatrix))), std::free);
if(!hough_spaces) throw std::bad_alloc(); // Useful, if you actually handle bad-allocs. If you ignore failed callocs, you'll likely segfault when accessing the data.
```

Clang and gcc will optimize this into a single `calloc`/`free` pair:
https://godbolt.org/z/m4rzRq

---

A totally different approach would be to try using a 3D Tensor instead of a vector of matrices:

```
typedef Eigen::Tensor<int, 3> HoughSpace;
HoughSpace hough_spaces(num_spaces,30,150);
hough_spaces.setZero();
```

Looking at the [generated assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/Kq3ziv) this looks semi-optimal though, even with `-O3 -DNDEBUG`.

---

Overall, note that benchmarking anything memory-related may be misleading. E.g., the call to `calloc` may return nearly instantaneous but on a lower level point to unallocated pages, which makes actually accessing them the first time more expensive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It was very helpful. I tried all variants, unfortunately they still weren't fast enough for my code to run in real time. 
But they gave me some ideas on how to restructure the code to bypass this whole problem, so I should be able to get it running.

Answer (score 1):

The interesting part is that `Eigen::Matrix` appears to have no constructor to initialize the elements. From [Eigen: The Matrix class](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html):

> ```
> Matrix3f a;
> ```

-> no allocations, no initialization of elements

> ```
> MatrixXf a(10,15);
> ```

-> allocated but uninitialized elements

Finally (!) some constructors that allow to initialize elements for small sized vectors:

> ```
> Vector2d a(5.0, 6.0);
> Vector3d b(5.0, 6.0, 7.0);
> Vector4d c(5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0);
> ```

If you read on to [Eigen: Advanced initialization](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html) you can find

> **Special matrices and arrays**
>
> The Matrix and Array classes have static methods like Zero(), which
>   can be used to initialize all coefficients to zero. [...]
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> std::cout << "A fixed-size array:\n";
> Array33f a1 = Array33f::Zero();
> std::cout << a1 << "\n\n";
> ```

**PS**

> But that was rather slow. Is there a faster way?

Whithout knowing more details about what exaclt you mean with "slow" it is hard to discuss details. All I can say is that I would expect initialization only to be faster than allocating unitialized elements and then `setZero()`.